# Playing youtube videos with vlcj not working anymore

Tags: java, ubuntu, youtube, vlc, vlcj

I am having a problem playing youtube videos with vlcj. Until last week or so everything was working.
i was calling mediaPlayer.playMedia("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1t8fl96HPQI") and was working fine but not anymore. it doesnt produce any errors at all. 
Note that i can play local files and other online streaming urls, but not youtube videos.

This is the code i am using. ( basically its a ready example)

```
/*
 * This file is part of VLCJ.
 *
 * VLCJ is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * VLCJ is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with VLCJ.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 * 
 * Copyright 2009, 2010, 2011 Caprica Software Limited.
 */

package com.javacodegeeks.youtube.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_media_t;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.test.VlcjTest;

/**
 * A minimal YouTube player.
 * <p>
 * The URL/MRL must be in the following format:
 * <pre>
 *   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=000000
 * </pre>
 * The only thing that makes this different from a 'regular' media player
 * application is the following piece of code:
 * <pre>
 *   mediaPlayer.setPlaySubItems(true); // <--- This is very important for YouTube media
 * </pre>
 * Note that it is also possible to programmatically play the sub-item in 
 * response to events - this is slightly more complex but more flexible.
 * <p>
 * The YouTube web page format changes from time to time. This means that the
 * lua scripts that vlc provides to parse the YouTube web pages when looking
 * for the media to stream may not work. If you get errors, especially errors
 * alluding to malformed urls, then you may need to update your vlc version to
 * get newer lua scripts.
 */
public class NewClass extends VlcjTest {

  private MediaPlayerFactory factory;
  private EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  private Frame mainFrame;

  private JLabel urlLabel;
  private JTextField urlTextField;
  private JButton playButton;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    setLookAndFeel();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new NewClass().start();
      }
    });
  }

  public NewClass() {
    mainFrame = new Frame("vlcj YouTube Test");
    mainFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/vlcj-logo.png")).getImage());
    mainFrame.setSize(800, 600);
    mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        exit(0);
      }
    });
    mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel cp = new JPanel();
    cp.setBackground(Color.black);
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel ip = new JPanel();
    ip.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
    ip.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ip, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    urlLabel = new JLabel("URL:");
    urlLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic('u');
    urlLabel.setToolTipText("Enter a URL in the format http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=000000");
    urlTextField = new JTextField(40);
    urlTextField.setFocusAccelerator('u');
    urlTextField.setToolTipText("Enter a URL in the format http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=000000");
    playButton = new JButton("Play");
    playButton.setMnemonic('p');

    ip.add(urlLabel);
    ip.add(urlTextField);
    ip.add(playButton);

    cp.add(ip, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    Canvas vs = new Canvas();
    vs.setBackground(Color.black);
    cp.add(vs, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    mainFrame.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    urlTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        play();
      }
    });

    playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        play();
      }
    });

    factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

    mediaPlayer = factory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(factory.newVideoSurface(vs));

    mediaPlayer.setPlaySubItems(true); // <--- This is very important for YouTube media

    mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mediaSubItemAdded(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, libvlc_media_t subItem) {
        List<String> items = mediaPlayer.subItems();
        System.out.println(items);
        System.out.println(mediaPlayer.subItemCount());
      }
    });
  }

  private void start() {
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private void play() {
    String mrl = urlTextField.getText();
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl);

  }

  private void exit(int value) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    factory.release();
    System.exit(value);
  }

  /**
   * Set the cross platform look and feel.
   * 
   * @throws Exception if an error occurs
   */

//  private static void setLookAndFeel() throws Exception {
//    String lookAndFeelClassName = null;
//    LookAndFeelInfo[] lookAndFeelInfos = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
//    for(LookAndFeelInfo lookAndFeel : lookAndFeelInfos) {
//      if("Nimbus".equals(lookAndFeel.getName())) {
//        lookAndFeelClassName = lookAndFeel.getClassName();
//      }
//    }
//    if(lookAndFeelClassName == null) {
//      lookAndFeelClassName = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
//    }
//    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeelClassName);
//  }
}
```

For youtube videos you want this code:

```
mediaPlayer.setPlaySubItems(true); // <--- This is very important for YouTube media
```

and the code below gets all subitems.

```
mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mediaSubItemAdded(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, libvlc_media_t subItem) {
        List<String> items = mediaPlayer.subItems();
        System.out.println(items);
        System.out.println(mediaPlayer.subItemCount());
      }
    });
```

When it was working, i noticed that the above code was printing 2 subitems, one of them being the actual url of the video.

But now it only prints one subitem like this:

[http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=1t8fl96HPQI&el=detailpage]

which is not the actual url of the video and i think thats why is not playing.

Any ideas of why this is happening? Did google change anything in the format of their youtube pages?

I tried upgrading the vlc youtube.lua file as was suggested in a tutorial i found but with no luck.

Also, when i use the same link in vlc, it works fine.

Specs:

Ubuntu 12.0.4 64 bits

VLC media player 2.0.5 Twoflower

vlcj 2.2.0

Thanks in advance,

Marios

Answer (score 0):

> Did google change anything in the format of their youtube pages?

Most likely. This happens all the time, to the point where I don't rely on this functionality in my application (even though it'd be nice if I could.) It's just too temperamental, one small change to the layout of Youtube and it stops working. I'm not sure the Lua file VLCJ uses is the same as the install of VLC (though I could be wrong there.)